# How can I run this perl script to operate on MongoDB?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have seen a usage perl script used to pre-split data [Link](https://gist.github.com/857469)

Question> How do I run this script?

The reason why I am asking this question is that the perl script doesn't include a typical statement as follows：

```
use MongoDB;
```

Also, I don't see it uses the MongoDB Perl Driver.

/// Updated ///
Here is the output from the script:

```
use admin;
db.runCommand({split: "archive.postings", middle: { PostingID: 95326 } });
db.runCommand({moveChunk: "archive.postings", find: { PostingID: 95326 }, to: "archive001"});
db.runCommand({split: "archive.postings", middle: { PostingID: 190651 } });
db.runCommand({moveChunk: "archive.postings", find: { PostingID: 190651 }, to: "archive002"});
db.runCommand({split: "archive.postings", middle: { PostingID: 285976 } });
db.runCommand({moveChunk: "archive.postings", find: { PostingID: 285976 }, to: "archive003"});
db.runCommand({split: "archive.postings", middle: { PostingID: 381301 } });
db.runCommand({moveChunk: "archive.postings", find: { PostingID: 381301 }, to: "archive001"});
db.runCommand({split: "archive.postings", middle: { PostingID: 476626 } });
db.runCommand({moveChunk: "archive.postings", find: { PostingID: 476626 }, to: "archive002"});
db.runCommand({split: "archive.postings", middle: { PostingID: 571951 } });
db.runCommand({moveChunk: "archive.postings", find: { PostingID: 571951 }, to: "archive003"});
```

Question> First, I run the above script on MongoDB. Now if I insert a doc as follows:

```
db.postings.insert({PostingID ： 95327， xx ： xxxxxxxx})
```

Will MongoDB send the inserted data on archive001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, it looks like the script is just there to create a set of commands that you should be able to run in Mongo to pre-shard your database.

It then becomes pretty simple when you think about it... No need for Mongo if it's not even going to run the commands! :-)

Answer (score 1):

That script effectively generates a script for MongoDB.